# how to compare 2 tables, remove old records and add new records sql

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, comparison

I have 2 sql tables that are exactly the same format, 1 being used as a temporary table and 1 being used as a static table.

Currently my code just wipes the static table and populates it each time with the new data from the temp table, but this isn't exactly what I need. I am trying to create some type of sql diff that compares the 2 tables, that will then delete the records that aren't in the temporary table but are in the static table, and it will add new records that are in the temp table but not the static table. So the static table is only being updated each run instead of being wiped and re-written.

So if my temp table has: ABC1, ABC2, ABC4
and my static table has: ABC1, ABC3, ABC4

My sql query would ideally return: ABC1, ABC2, ABC4

I have 2 queries that seem to select the values I want to remove and the ones I want to add, but I currently can't get the delete one to function properly so I am wondering if there is something I am missing from the query.

This query inserts the data that is in the temp table, but not the static table:

```
 Insert into [static table] 
    SELECT * 
  FROM [temp table]

EXCEPT

SELECT *
  FROM [static table]
```

This query should delete the data that's in static table but not the temp table:

```
 delete from [static table] 
 where not exists 
    (SELECT *
  FROM [static table]

EXCEPT

SELECT *
  FROM [temp table] )
```

Can anyone suggest what the problem is with my query or if there's a better way to perform this task? Thanks

Comment: What flavour SQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) which was introduced in SQL 2008.

e.g. untested, but something like...

```
MERGE StaticTable AS target
USING TempTable AS source ON target.ColumnA = source.ColumnA
-- value doesn't exist in the target table, so add it
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (ColumnA) VALUES (source.ColumnA)
-- value doesn't exist in the source table, so delete from target
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE
```

Edit: To work on multiple columns, something like:

```
 MERGE StaticTable AS target
    USING TempTable AS source ON target.ColumnA = source.ColumnA 
        AND target.ColumnB = source.ColumnB
    -- value doesn't exist in the target table, so add it
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
        INSERT (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES (source.ColumnA, source.ColumnB)
    -- value doesn't exist in the source table, so delete from target
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
        DELETE
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this merge but use all column headings? Just I don't have a key field as my records work for several languages, so the ID could appear for a few languages, that why I need to base the search on a few columns.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that 'merge' should do what you want. 
Here are the details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have any defined unique keys you can probably use IN syntax:

```
DELETE FROM static WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id from temporary);
INSERT INTO static WHERE id IN(SELECT id from temporary) AND NOT id IN (SELECT id from static);
```

Comment: I don't have a unique key because my records are for all different languages, so the same ID could appear for a few languages. When I try your suggestion I get: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."